Proper way to send json with schema message via kafka-console-producer
I want to test my kafka/connect/schema registry configuration i have set up locally with docker-compose. initially - i set up a connect instance with a s3 sink plugin that writes incoming json messages to s3 in avro format. I was able to send messages with the format
{"schema": {...}, "payload": {...}}

and see that the kafka-connect is able to parse and manage to sink the data correctly to s3 in avro format.
Now i want to work with the schema registry to avoid sending the schema in every message. im using io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter for my key and value converters.
When i try to test it - i produce a message with the kafka-console-producer utility and get the following error:
[2024-12-12 15:00:02,140] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=my-s3-sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:230)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:536)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:513)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:349)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:250)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:219)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:204)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:259)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:237)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error of topic my-topic: 
    at io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter.toConnectData(JsonSchemaConverter.java:144)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$4(WorkerSinkTask.java:536)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:214)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing JSON message for id -1
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.java:238)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.deserializeWithSchemaAndVersion(AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.java:315)
    at io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter$Deserializer.deserialize(JsonSchemaConverter.java:193)
    at io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter.toConnectData(JsonSchemaConverter.java:127)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.getByteBuffer(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:645)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.java:129)
    ... 20 more

This is how i produced my message:
./bin/kafka-console-producer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --property schema.registry.url=schemaregistry:8085 --property value.schema.id=1 --topic my-topic
> {...}

im assuming that the producer is not generating the message correctly. Is that true? if so - how can i use the kafka-console-producer to produce a message that will successfully be processed? if it has nothing to do with the producer - what else are possible culprits?
Here are my configurations:
docker-compose.yaml:
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.8.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: "2181"
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: "2000"
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: "zookeeper:22888:23888"
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.8.0
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_BROKER_RACK: "r1"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "schemaregistry:8085"

  schemaregistry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.8.0
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: "zookeeper:2181"
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schemaregistry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8085"
      KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092"
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "kafka:9092"
    ports:
      - 8085:8085

  connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:7.7.2
    container_name: connect
    hostname: connect
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - schemaregistry
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "kafka:9092"
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: connect-cluster
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: _connect-configs
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: _connect-offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: _connect-status
      # CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      # CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      # CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      # CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schemaregistry:8085"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schemaregistry:8085"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: /usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components
      CONNECT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "localhost"
    volumes:
      - ./connect/s3/connectors/confluentinc-kafka-connect-s3-10.5.19:/usr/share/confluent-hub-components

s3-connect.properties:
{
    "name": "my-s3-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "my-topic",
        "topics.dir": "my-dir",
        "behavior.on.null.values": "ignore",
        "s3.region": "my-region",
        "s3.bucket.name": "my-bucket",
        "s3.part.size": "5242880",
        "aws.access.key.id": "bla-bla-bla",
        "aws.secret.access.key": "bla-bla-bla",
        "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
        "flush.size": "5",
        "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.avro.AvroFormat",
        "schema.compatibility": "NONE",
        "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.FieldPartitioner",
        "partition.field.name": "partitionFieldName"
    }
}


Confluent Platform comes with kafka-json-schema-console-producer shell script. You should use this instead of kafka-console-producer

Also, do not set these (they are deprecated) and should never be changed from JsonConverter class
CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER
CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER


You can also remove Zookeeper; Kafka doesn't need it

Thanks for the response. the kafka image im using confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.8.0 does not contain the kafka-json-schema-console-producer in the /bin directory. Do you recommend a different image/tag that does have that producer?

@MrT. It is not in /bin, but that doesn't mean the script isn't there in the container

From error message org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte results in first 4 bytes of your serialized message is missing schemaId(this way works Confluent Schema (de)serializers). You have to provide  io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer as producer parameter, so that schema id will be injected in your message.
./bin/kafka-console-producer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --property schema.registry.url=schemaregistry:8085 --property value.schema.id=1 --topic my-topic --property value.serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer
> {...}

And also you will need to add kafka-json-schema-serializer jar in kafka libs directory.

Thanks for your response - unfortunately it did not resolve the issue. I added the jar via volume to the container and added the CLASSPATH env var in the docker compose as suggested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50859767/add-jar-to-general-kafka-connect-classpath-in-the-confluent-docker
when i ran the command
kafka-console-producer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic my-topic --property schema.registry.url=schemaregistry:8085 --property value.schema.id=1 --property value.serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer the result was the same.

The issue seems to be with how you're producing your messages.
When running the following command:
./bin/kafka-console-producer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --property schema.registry.url=schemaregistry:8085 --property value.schema.id=1 --topic my-topic
You are in fact generating the message without any schema (the Kafka console producer does not use the *schema* properties and is, in fact, ignoring them completely).
As mentioned above by OneCricketeer, you would need to use the kafka-json-schema-console-producer shell script instead. What it does behind the scenes is a 2-step process:

Call the schema-registry REST API that fetches the relevant schema.
Serialize the message according to the schema (In case of json - I believe it's just validation. In case of Avro - it's also actual serialization).
Produce the serialized bytes content to Kafka.

You can read the Bash script code here.

From a quick glance at some documentation and schema-registry code in Github, I believe you cannot pass the schema ID and have to pass the complete schema (--property value.schema=...).
This would usually not be an issue with production code as the Kafka Confluent SDK caches schema IDs for each given schema. See code here

FYI, the Docker image you mentioned does contain the script, and you can definitely use it for producing your test message:
❯ docker run -ti confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.8.0 ls /bin/kafka-json-schema-console-producer /bin/kafka-json-schema-console-producer
Good luck!
